# Calling geonames.org service multiple times in ActionScript3 and adding each result to an arrayCollection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, asynchronous, flex4, flash-builder

I am using a service that returns JSON (geonames.org) and I'm putting the result in an array and dumping it to a datagrid.  Now that works fine for one city like this http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?placename=San+Diego&username=demo"

However, I want to call this service multiple times with different city names, so I created an XML list ad figured I would iterate over the city list and get the results.

My question is how do I do this such that 1) all the lists are combined into one arraycollection and 2) this seems like I will have to chain the calls and wait for results which may or may not come back, so I thought I would ask the group about the best practice, and or resources to read and examples to build from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Set up your data object as a class that extends array collection.
- Add a method to add a new result to the collection (it will test if the result already exists and add it cleanly in the right place)
- In your event listener for the JSON result, pass the result to the method you've made on your data object
- In case of errors, do any cleanup necessary.
- If you need to wait for the entire query to return all or fail, you can add a counter to the results that iterates in both the success and fail handlers.

That should do it.

Comment: Just reading this now, and that is exactly what I ended up doing, but thanks for providing a succinct and clear solution that is exactly what stackoverflow is about. Real people and real solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! If that answers your question, please feel free to vote it up and accept it. :)